# Передача строки стринг из вектора в функцию в с++

Tags: c++, vector

есть вектор имен файлов с их путем, в цикле передается функции для подсчета значений из файла,так вот при передачи строки из вектора происходит ошибка в чем дело?
Обязательные условия:
1)передавать нужно всегда первое значение из списка
2)функция counting не должна изменять переданный ей аргумент

```
std::vector<std::string> files;

...

while(!files.empty()) {

    Counting(files.begin());
    ...
    // Удалить первый элемент
    files.erase(files.begin());
}

...

void Counting(const std::string &name){
...
```

выводит ошибку

```
main.cpp|25|error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const string&' {aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'} from expression of type 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator' {aka '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >'}|
```

Comment: Ну написано же, ты пытаешься инициализировать ссылку на  строку итератором на неё.

Comment: Что касается примененного вами решения, оно в крайней степени не оптимально - почитайте историю про маляра Шлемиэля для лучшего понимания, почему не оптимально. Гораздо лучше пройти массив в цикле, ничего не удаляя, а потом методом .clear() опустошить его.

Comment: @gbg, или использовать `std::list`

Comment: @megorit в современной практике, использование связных списков нежелательно, и вот почему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170566/bjarne-stroustrup-says-we-must-avoid-linked-lists

Comment: @gbg, а давайте представим, что каждый элемент листа весит по паре десятков мегабайт. Всё еще неоптимально?

Comment: @megorit поясните пожалуйста, что вы хотите показать своим примером? Ну весит элемент листа пару десятков мегабайт, к каким трудностям это приведет?

Comment: @gbg, не к трудностям, а к тому, что использованее `std::list`, `std::set` и `std::map` станет куда оптимальнее.

Comment: @megorit, Эта гипотеза не имеет отношения к случаю, который описал автор (std::string весит десятки байт).

Comment: Более того, @megorit, в реалиях современной 64 битной ОС, гораздо удобнее под эти блобы выделить заранее огромный линейный буфер, и ссылаться на него по указателям.

Comment: Управлять памятью самому во многих случаях куда лучше, но куда накладнее по времени для программиста (разработка и отладка).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `begin()` возвращает не элемент вектора (строку в вашем случае), а итератор, показывающий на этот элменет. Так что вам надо его разименовать - `Counting(*files.begin())`, а еще лучше, использовать другой метод
`Counting(files.front())`